# Get Product Name and Description in WooCommerce email templates

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-templates, orders

I am trying to get product descripton and the product name when email is sent in WooCommerce email templates.

I am able to get product id `$order_id = trim(str_replace('#', '', $order->get_items()));` using this code

But when I am trying to get its description and product name I am not able to do the same.

My code:

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);

    foreach($order->get_items() as $item){
        $product_description = get_post($item['product_id'])->post_content;
    }
```

How can I make it work?

Thanks

I added this in function.php what i ma trying to do is after the order is set completed i am trying to send sms to the user but when i set it as completed  it gives an 500 error

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'my_function' );
    /*
        * Do something after WooCommerce sets an order on completed
    */
    function my_function($order_id) {



        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {

            $product_name = $item['name']; // product name

            $product_id = $order->get_item_meta($item_id, '_product_id', true); // product ID

            $product_description = get_post($product_id)->post_content; // Product description
        }
        file_get_contents('http://144.76.39.175/api.php?username=xxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxxx&route=1&message%5B%5D=ProductName'.$product_name.'&sender=xxxxx&mobile%5B%5D=xxxxxx');



    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do that you have to change a little bit your code.

Also I am not sure that you need to get the **`$order`** object and the order ID as the **`$order`** object already exist.

So you could try first without **`$order = new WC_Order($order_id);`** (or **`$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );`**) at the beginning of the code. If it doesn't work without, you will just add it again.

Here is the code:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // optional (to test without it)

foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {

    $product_name = $item['name']; // product name

    $product_id = $order->get_item_meta($item_id, '_product_id', true); // product ID

    $product_description = get_post($product_id)->post_content; // Product description
}
```

This code is tested and works.

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

Comment: and i am adding this in woocommerce/template/email/complete, cancelled refunded/php's coz as soon as email is send i need an sms to be sent

Comment: can i add the same in email templates php ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi so the complete code needed to be inserted is?:
Also what should be changed to send this for the processing action instead of the status_comleted?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'my_function' );

/*
 * Do something after WooCommerce sets an order on completed
 */

function my_function($order_id) 
{
    f$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // optional (to test without it)
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
    $product_name = $item['name']; // product name
    $product_id = $order->get_item_meta($item_id, '_product_id', true); // product ID
    $product_description = get_post($product_id)->post_content; // Product description
}
```